# Eliminating spikes in sensor measurements

Tags: algorithm, arduino

I am measuring pwm signals. There are two states. The measurement is either very close to 1000 or to 2000;
I don't want to average the values to get rid of measurement noise. I just one to get rid of one or two values that are very imprecise.

To give an example this is the expected(accurate) data graph:

[image]

This is the real measurement data graph:

[image]

I want to eliminate the spike in the middle which is caused by just 3 or 4 measurements. I want to ignore those measurements.

I actually thought that I would create a queue of 10 elements and push the measurements in it. if the new measurement is 500 less or more than the average of the values in the queue, then it would not add to the actual data array. Whenever the difference between the average of the queue and the new measurement is less than 500, which is 5 measurements in a 10 element queue, I would start adding to the actual data array and reset the queue.

But It didn't seem like an efficient way to do it. I am a math noob, yet. So I don't know how to write it more efficiently and I need efficiency since the code will be working on an Arduino.

Thank you

Edit:

I tried using Median Filtering as suggested

This is my **actual** measurement graph:
[image]

And this is the median filter applied graph:

[image]

As you can see, it worked perfectly. However, I had to use a filter with a length of 20. That is a lot of data to cache and push to the queue. Especially in Ardunio,c++, which has just 16 megahertz of processing power. Is there a more efficient way for my case?

Comment: Is the x-axis (time) in seconds, or milliseconds or what? How many readings (samples) are measured in each unit of time?

Comment: I would have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_filter

Comment: @MarkSetchell these graphs are not actual representation of my case. But you can think of the time as seconds and I read a value in every 20 ms. So there are a lot of measurements in that graph

Comment: I am a highschool IB High-level math student. Should I just give up coding and wait for college. I am trying to learn math as I go

Comment: More efficient, how, exactly?  What are your specifications, requirements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @mcdowella suggested. I converted all of my input to ones and zeros.

I am not using median filter since the I will be using the elimination in realtime.

I just take the average of last 10 values that my servo generate and round it to collect my final value. So when 0 are dominant in the last 10 values, I use 0.

This method has a downside of delay. When my sensor starts to measure 0 values, my algorithm detects it after 5 measurement cyles. 25 ms for each. There is a 250 ms of delay.

I know this is a lazy solution but it seems to work for me. Though, @mcdowella's answer is very very informative. I hope future readers can benefit it more than I could

Answer (score 1):

I am going to assume that the question is now how to speed up a median filter for an Arduino. My experience with the Arduino is limited to complaining about data produced by it that wasn't regularly sampled. Apparently that went away when they shifted to Raspberry Pi because the Raspberry Pi is a lot more powerful so that might be one option.

I don't know how you are calculating the median filter but a web search suggests that there are a few implementations out there that you could try out. If starting from C++ STL you can compute a running median using data structures that allow you to insert, delete, and find the largest or smallest item. Keep a pool of N/2 items above the median and a pool of N/2 items below the median. When you get a new data point, remove the oldest value and compare the new value with the median and put it in whichever pool that points to. Now you might have N/2+1 items on one side and N/2-1 on the other side. If so then, for example, remove the smallest item from the top pool and insert it in the bottom pool. Recompute the median as the average of the smallest item now in the top and the largest item now in the bottom (if N is odd you have a median item outside the pool and the book-keeping as just a little more complicated). The cost of accepting a new datapoint is now O(log N) instead of O(N) or worse, so this may help.

(FWIW the most impressive programmers I have known were also expert mathematicians, so I would keep up the maths).

Come to think of it, if every value really is either 1000 or 2000 you don't need fancy data structures: all you need is a circular buffer and a running count of the number of values >= 2000 within the buffer, which you can update as you delete the oldest value and add the newest. This would cost you 20 ints, but if your values really are 1000 or 2000, each value can be represented by a single bit, so you can hold the entire queue within a single 32-bit word, and count the number of set bits with POPCNT, if arduino C/C++ provides it